# Using UIStackView with SizeClasses and supported iOS version

Tags: ios, interface-builder, size-classes, uistackview

I have an iOS app that uses SizeClasses.

1. When the app is running on iPad(wR hR) I would like to use UIStackView. This will only be iOS 9+ version that should run iPad version.
2. But when running on iPhone(wC hR) I will not use UIStackView. And this can be iOS version 7+.

Is SizeClasses "installed" in Interface Builder used for situations like this?

Hope I explain it alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install/uninstall views for different Size Class from IB: [See this apple link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html)

But you can't do this on the basis of OS version. If you want to use Stack View kind component on iOS 7 try [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView).